# passing jquery array to php - unexpected format and count() value and variable passing issue

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am passing a jquery array called 'selected' full of ids along with the opening of an ajax modal.

```
$('#dtDelete').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal-ajax').load('/modals/m__delete.php?selected='+selected);
    $('#modal-ajax').modal('show');                         
});
```

On the modal php page `count($_GET['selected']);` always returns 1 no matter what.  I am trying to get an actual count of the number of values in the array. Turns out this is because the array is a string as noted below.

`var_dump($_GET['selected']);` returns something along the lines of `string(69) "187419,187420,187413,187414,187415,187416,187417,187418,187421,187422"` which is something I am not accustomed to (sort of new to jquery).  I need to do processing in php using foreach on this array.  Can I 'convert' this to a 'normal' php array so count() will work as expected and I can process it normally in php?

Lastly, this array may or may not be extremely large at times.  The jquery function above opens an ajax modal (I am using the modal as a confirmation box for the user whether they really want to delete the entries in the selected array) and I know the $_GET method has limits to the amount of data it can pass.  I can't do $_POST because this is a modal and I need to load it then show it... how else can I pass this data?

Comment: How does your jquery array looks like?

Comment: See the var_dump I posted above.  I was using selected.push to create it.

Comment: @user756659: consider using `var_dump(explode(',', $_GET['selected']));`, or pass a JSON string to PHP, or use `$.ajax`...

Comment: then use implode to get an array.

Comment: @kumar_v: `implode` turns an array into a string, I take it you mean `explode` ;-P

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes you are correct. Sorry for my mistake. :-)

Comment: Using explode(), while giving me a better looking array to work with in php still gives me a false negative for count().  If there are zero entries in the array I still get `array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }` as a result which returns '1' as the count().

Comment: just use `array_filter()` on it, it removes empty values by default: `var_dump(count(array_filter($array)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['selected']
```

returns the STRING after the attribute 'selected', and count(string) is 1 not matter what ( it's not a multi-dimension array to be greater than 1).

As for the comma separated string example you gave, you may use the following :

```
  $selected = $_GET['selected'];
  //test wether the string has contents
  if(strlen($selected)!=0) {
     $selected_array = explode(',',$selected); //this is the new array that you want
  }
  else {
     //the string is empty
  }
```

There are many string functions you may check at : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: So how can I do a true test if the array has actual contents or not?  Using this count() will return 1 if there are no actual ids being passed as you pointed out above. If there are contents it returns the correct value, but I am only interested in 'nothing' or 'something'.

Comment: Nope... it returns 1... the vardump is `array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: Woops right. You may do this extra check : if(strpos($selected,',') != null) $selected_array = explode(',', $selected);